# Please migrate the question templates to CommonMark

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, stackapps

We have three templates for new questions (for apps, libraries and scripts):

[image]

They'll insert a body like this:

> ```
> <!-- thumbnail: https://example.com/some-image.png -->
> <!-- version: 1.0 -->
> <!-- tag: a-tag-on-the-post -->
> <!-- excerpt: Up to 200 characters of excerpt -->
>
> ##Screenshot / Code Snippet
>
> Insert a reasonably sized screenshot (or code snippet) of your 
> app here, so we can get a quick look at it and 
> an idea of how it works and what it might do for us.
>
> ...
> ```

which unfortunately isn't compatible with [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232). So new questions like [this one](https://stackapps.com/q/8727/34061) end up poorly formatted. Can the templates please be updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed. Here's how the templates currently look like:

> ```
> <!-- thumbnail: https://example.com/some-image.png -->
> <!-- version: 1.0 -->
> <!-- tag: a-tag-on-the-post -->
> <!-- excerpt: Up to 200 characters of excerpt -->
>
> ## Screenshot / Code Snippet
> ...
>
> ## About
> ...
>
> ## License
> ...
>
> ## About
> ...
>
> ## Download
> .... etc.
> ```